# Missing file after mv

Tags: mv, hidden-files

Hope you can help me with this issue.

I did the following:

```
mv filename .foldername
```

after that the file is gone and a hidden folder foldername was created .foldername

when `cd .foldername` I got a Not a directory answer.

Getting desperate I did:

```
mv .foldername /foldername
```

and then `.foldername` all together is gone.
I can not locate the original file filename.
Please help!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You renamed 'filename' to .foldername  (it would have moved it if it didn't exist, assuming it didnt the mv was the equivalent to a rename).  I would have expected your second `mv` (to /foldername) to have responded as a permissions error (users generally don't have write access to /) but if you didn't get an error, it'll be /foldername   `mv` means move; it moves the file as requested.  If you've forgotten your exact commands, view `history` to see what they were (including date & time executed if enabled)

Comment: thank you. Where is /foldername then?

Comment: /foldername    - it should be in the / folder (assuming you have write access to it). The response you got when you gave your second command will say if the `mv` took place (no response = success)

Comment: I got no response but what is / folder?